# Prove OrganizationServiceProxy is not Thread Safe

Tags: thread-safety, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2015

I want to prove that re-using instances of OrganizationServiceProxy between threads will cause problems.

This console app does not have a problem re-using the same instance of OrganizationServiceProxy between threads:

```c#
class Program
{
    private static OrganizationServiceProxy Service { get; set; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Connect(); // Initializes Service

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            int index = i;
            Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < 10; i2++)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Creating" + index);
                            Entity record = new Entity("account");
                            record.Id = new Guid("4986e130-45f7-e411-9454-00155d91de01");
                            record["name"] = index + " - " + i2;
                            Service.Update(record);
                            Console.WriteLine("Created" + index);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        { }
                    }
                });
        }
        Console.ReadLine(); // the name of the record ends up as 99 - 9, which is right
    }

    /* Initialize Service */
    private static bool Connect()
    {
        try
        {
            ClientCredentials cred = new ClientCredentials();
            cred.UserName.UserName = @"r";
            cred.UserName.Password = @"";
            IServiceManagement<IOrganizationService> serviceManagement = ServiceConfigurationFactory.CreateManagement<IOrganizationService>(new Uri(@"/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc"));
            Service = new OrganizationServiceProxy(serviceManagement, cred);
            var who = new Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages.WhoAmIRequest(); // used to test the connection
            var whoResponse = (Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages.WhoAmIResponse)Service.Execute(who); // this fails if not connected       
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting to CRM.\n" + e.Message + ((e.InnerException != null) ? "\n" + e.InnerException.Message : ""));
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

[The SDK states](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.client.organizationserviceproxy.aspx) that any instance members of OrganizationServiceProxy are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

How can I cause a problem with an OrganizationServiceProxy shared between threads?

What kinds of problem are to be expected?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I know the specific answer to your question, but something that is marked as not guaranteed of being thread-safe just means exactly that: It may be safe, but the author has not tested for it or specifically written any thread-safe code for those classes, and thus cannot guarantee thread safety.

I do know that thread-safety definitely comes into play with Plugins on the server. This is why you are not supposed to use local fields in a Plugin class. The Plugin engine re-uses the instances of your Plugin class instead of re-instantiating them for each execution. This means it is possible that your Plugin could execute with "old data" in those local fields that was used by the last thread, which could obviously cause all kinds of problems.

Comment: Also, it seems like this question is pointing to your desire to cache the OrganizationServiceProxy class instead of instantiating it in each thread. My observation is that this does not result in appreciable performance gains, as the main bottleneck is always the network in these cases. If this is where you are going, my suggestion is to test caching the Proxy and sharing it versus instantiating it for each thread. My guess is that you won't notice an appreciable difference either and then you won't have to worry about being thread-safe or not. :)

Comment: Disagree with the performance observation. I've seen perf issues when `OrganizationServiceProxy` is initiated for each thread. Obviously the materiality is going to depend on numbers but I saw a project with over a hundred queries and the cost of creating a new `OrganizationServiceProxy` was significant compared query performance - reuse gave us a 25%+ performance improvement. 

Adding to that `OrganizationServiceProxy` isn't applicable in plugins as it is a Client side class.

I agree with everything else, the SDK isn't saying it won't work necessarily, just that MSFT doesn't support it.